# pass $_FILES variable into the AJAX

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a form with file upload like the following:

```
<form name="addform" id="addform" method="post" action="add.php?action=add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
File 1: <input type="file" name="file1" />
<input name="add" type="submit" value="ADD">
</form>
```

I want to pass `$_FILES` variable in `AJAX` because I was used pop out dialog. Here is my `AJAX` that I tried to write:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'addanduploadfile.php',
    data: ?,
    success: function(msg)
    { 
         alert(msg);    
    }
});
```

But my problem is I don't know how to pass `$_FILES` into the `AJAX` and show the `file1` name on the `addanduploadfile.php`. How should I do?

Comment: use ajaxForm.  http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

Comment: Do you want file upload should be done by AJAX only?

Comment: you dont need PHP for this.

Comment: you can try this jquery plugin https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: @Apb Yes. I want to use AJAX to upload file.

Comment: @KKLMichael Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

1. [Multiple File Upload AJAX](http://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-using-jquery-ajax-php/).
2. [AJAX File upload](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
var file_data = $('#addform').prop('files')[0];// collect files 
var form_data = new FormData();// take other form data
form_data.append('file', file_data);// append the files to your data

$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'addanduploadfile.php',
     data: form_data, // pass form data here
     success: function(msg)
     { 
            alert(msg);    
     }
 });
```

Comment: In addanduploadfile.php, how should I show the file name?